# Subform Solution with Limited Space - MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, subforms

I've been looking and trying a bunch of different things but I can't solve my situation:

A room contains furniture. I need an inventory/details about this furniture as well as the room. The user measures the room with some other details, then IDEALLY would use subforms to add furniture and their details using a multi-item subform. However I have VERY LIMITED space. This is intended for a tablet PC, so screen space is next to nothing. I need to incorporate pictures and description boxes etc, so I basically have about 1-2 fields wide by 7-8 fields long to put my subform in.. problem is the furniture itself has about 15 fields.

So I think, due to space constraints and weird requirements, I need something that isn't a subform; maybe a link to another form which the user could add furniture without having to re-populate the Room information (ie the room number, building number etc).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subform but include only item name and quantity(?). Put an add button somewhere suitable and use that to add items to what ever form is contained in the current subform. The add button can open a an unbound or bound form.

Comment: How do I tell the detailed form what its parent room is? I've tried setting things at Form_Open() to change the recordset based on values in Forms!TheRoomForm!RoomName for example, but it is unreliable for several reasons. I do like the idea of a small subform to summarize to the user when they look at the room, then a button which leads to details. That's exactly what I was thinking to do; I just don't know how to set up the details form.

Comment: You can include a Where statement or an OpenArg in the OpenForm action. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141520(v=office.10).aspx You can even make the form modal.

Comment: Ahh, that's the info I needed! Thanks! I did look.. apparently not well enough.

Comment: One last problem with this; what happens if there is no record yet? When I `DoCmd.OpenForm` and no furniture is yet present, it will not open as the Where clause is causing no records to be displayed.. is there an argument which would open it to a new record?

Comment: Are you using a form / subform with a room as the main form? You can use OpenArgs and an add only (acFormAdd) or an unbound form. Set the relevant control to the room openarg (the openarg is set to parent.txtroom) in a suitable event (load, current, beforeupdate). Use the Where statement to edit existing records.

Comment: Fixed. Turns out it was a problem with the Form_Open event of the second form, not from the `DoCmd.OpenForm` function of the first. For some reason it won't allow me to have ANYTHING in the Form_Open() (not even leaving it empty) when opening it this way... weird.